# how to make an event at MKmapview in callOut?

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, customization, callouts

I have MKmapview with an annotation, then if I push or click a pin of annotation,it will show a CallOut such as title or subtitle. but I want to customize it and input an event, such as if I click a CallOut, I will be threw to another view. what should I do? any code to make an event if CallOut was clicked?

how to customize CallOut Bubble?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can assign leftCalloutAccessoryView and/or rightCalloutAccessoryView properties for your annotation's view - for example use a button there with appropriate action
2. When user taps annotation callout then annotation gets deselected and you can handle that event in map view's delegate `mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:` method
3. You can try to create you custom callout with whatever behaviour you want. There're several blog posts in the web with examples how to do that (e.g. [#1](http://www.jakeri.net/2009/12/custom-callout-bubble-in-mkmapview-final-solution/), [#2](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/))

Comment: mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView: works when we click the annotation not when we click the bubble.

Comment: @Jim Thio, just checked in my project - diddeselect method gets called when we tap callout... (tested on iPad simulator v4.3)